# Validate xsl fo in xslt stylesheet

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a little problem with validating xml, xslt in details.
I have an xslt stylesheet that transforms xml data source to xsl:fo document.
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master margin-top="25mm" margin-bottom="25mm" margin-left="25mm" margin-right="25mm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" master-name="simplePageLayout">
                <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" column-gap="0.25in" />
                <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" display-align="after" extent="0.1mm" padding-top="0pt" padding-left="0.4in" padding-right="0.4in" padding-bottom="0pt" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" display-align="before" extent="0.4in" padding-top="4pt" padding-left="0.4in" padding-right="0.4in" padding-bottom="0pt" />
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="default-sequence">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference master-reference="simplePageLayout" />
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-sequence">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block font-family="Segoe UI" color="#000000" font-size="9pt" />
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

What I want to do is to validate written xsl:fo elements, ignoring xsl tags. Is it possible?
For now I use dtd validation (I have xsd schema too) for validating Fo, but it gives me an error on each xsl tag.

Summary:
Is it possible to validate only fo elements against the schema, ignoring xsl tags, and how should I do it? Maybe a code snippet in C#, or a hint how to modify documents?

Comment: Quick question. It seems like your XSL template will always return the same output, no matter which file you apply against it. Is that what you expect?

I would expect that somewhere in your xslt file you would be referencing the writing elements from your original xml file.

Comment: It`s just a simple example :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do the schema validation against is the output *after* you do the transform, not against the XSLT document.  When you run the XSLT transformation against the input XML, the resulting output shouldn't contain any of the XSL tags.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a solution. I`m parsing document in the form as in example, and I need to validate it before transform occurs.